# How to choose between task queues and cron

Tags: cron, task-queue, cron-task

In our application, when a user creates a task, we need to send alerts to other users via message or email, if the other users don't respond or task is incomplete, alert will be send again after 5min(set by user) to their superiors about the task. If the task is completed no need to send additional alerts , the escalation goes on.. There may be more than 1000 users creating tasks simultaneously, for this kind of application, which is best approach creating a cron which runs every minute and get the information on open tasks so we can proceed, or creating tasks and adding them to queues. Both of them have their advantages and disadvantages. Which is the best practise in scenarios like this. Thank you

Comment: would you like to share the advantages and disadvantage you have in mind and are of relevance to you? also, I would only use `cron` for the simplest of use cases. It is archaic and hard to work with, and better tools exist, depending on your use case.

Comment: @shx2 if we use cron, after the cron is completed and gives us the open task, we have to send alerts meanwhile if another cron was started then the open tasks will be reported again and there is chance of duplication, if we use queues as per my knowledge, if we want to cancel any thread we have to refer the entire queue to null and form it again. so it may effect other tasks..